# Firestore collection documents accessible directly but not with stream()

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am using simple `Firestore` database with chats collection inside which each chat document has collection of message documents. If I want to access specific message I can do following request

```
msg_ref = self.db.collection('chats').document(chat_id).collection('messages').document(msg_id)
```

I can also access all of the messages for given chat

```
msgs_ref = db.collection('chats').document(chat_id).collection('messages')
    for doc in msgs_ref.stream():
        print(doc.id)
```

But I cannot understand why following command returns empty list

```
chat_ref = db.collection('chats').get()
```

And as a result this call never enters `for loop`

```
chat_ref = db.collection('chats')
for doc in chat_ref.stream():
   print(doc.id)
```

Looking at [example](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-get-all-documents#firestore_data_get_all_documents-python) from official documentation

```
docs = db.collection(u'cities').stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

I completely don't understand what I might be doing wrong here. Can someone please explain why this is not working

```
chat_ref = db.collection('chats')
for doc in chat_ref.stream():
   print(doc.id)
```

And whether I can do anything to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging on SO I've found answer by Doug Stevenson (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72588031/1080517) where he pointed out that if documents are greyed out and in italics those are not actual documents. And I believe this is my case as well.

Comment: LO answer to another SO answer.